# Inserting a Row in BigQuery with Nested Record using C# API

Tags: c#, json, google-bigquery

I'm trying to insert a row (with nested records) into BigQuery using the C# API.  I'm able to insert a row (w/ nested records) using the JavaScript API. But using the C# API i'm getting error saying: "Repeated field must be imported as a JSON Array". He is a simple row that I was able to insert using the JavaScript API

```
var json = {'rows':[{'json':
  {"inputs" : [{
      "Age":"10"
  }]}}]};
```

This works fine in JS, but I'm unclear how to do this in C#.

Here is my attempt:

```
var r = new TableDataInsertAllRequest.RowsData();
r.Json = new Dictionary<string, object>();
var dict = new Dictionary<string, object>();
dict.Add("Age", "10");
r.Json.Add("inputs", dict);
```

Also I tried using JSON API

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(input, jsonSettings);
var dict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(json, jsonSettings);
r.Json.Add("jsonInputs", dict);
```

Here is the API Doc for RowsData https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/bigquery/v2/csharp/latest/classGoogle_1_1Apis_1_1Bigquery_1_1v2_1_1Data_1_1TableDataInsertAllRequest_1_1RowsData.html

Its somewhat vague or unclear how to do nested records.  I tried just writing straight JSON but getting the same errors.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the json example that works there are two arrays. I don't see any arrays in either of two failing examples you provide.

I suspect adding the arrays will fix your problem. Consider parsing the known-working json string into a json object and using that as a quick test.

Answer (score 0):

The following code snippet successfully works for bigquery:

```
JArray inputs = new JArray();
JObject inputOne = new JObject(new JProperty("Age", "12"));
inputOne.Add(new JProperty("BirthDate", "1234"));
r.Json.Add("inputs", inputs);
```

Comment: Dude, can you give me a complete example pls? Because i have tried this but it doesn't seem to work.